# how to express $\dfrac{dH(z)}{dz}$, if $H(z)=\int_{z-1}^1{f(x, z)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

if $$H(z)=\int_{z-1}^1f(z,x)dx\\0<z<2$$,then

$$H'(z)=\;?$$

Comment: It is a prerequisite for questions of this this nature that you show your efforts on how to solve this

Comment: See this for the complete statement, together with conditions on $f$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to apply the following identity:
$$\begin{align}H(z) &= \int_{g(z)}^{h(z)} f(z, x)\operatorname{d}x \\
H'(z) & = f(z, h(z))h'(z) - f(z, g(z))g'(z) + \int_{g(z)}^{h(z)} \frac{\partial f(z, x)}{\partial z}\operatorname{d}x.\end{align}$$
Proof of this identity is left as an exercise for the reader. Hint: use the directional derivative on $\int_{g(z)}^{h(z)} f(y, x)\operatorname{d}x$.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement